# Bind to object property

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, actionscript, air, mxml

AS

```
[Bindable]
var object:Object = {
    property: "Property"
};
```

MXML

```
<s:Label text="{object.property}"/>
```

The labels text will be "Property", but if object.property is changed, the label isn't updated. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Properties of an object or collection will not dispatch a property change event unless implemented.

Likewise to your example, a change to an Array element will not be bound.

Collections such as ArrayCollection wrap objects within a proxy to dispatch events for binding.

Use an `ObjectProxy` to dispatch changes to your object.

Instantiate an ObjectProxy and listen for PropertyChangeEvent:

```
objectProxy = new ObjectProxy(object);
objectProxy.addEventListener(PropertyChangeEvent.PROPERTY_CHANGE, propertyChangeHandler);
```

Access your object via the proxy, such as setting a property named 'property':

```
objectProxy.property = "Hello, world";
```

This example creates an ObjectProxy with a timer to change the 'property' member every second:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               minWidth="955"
               minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler(event)">


    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.events.PropertyChangeEvent;
            import mx.utils.ObjectProxy;


            private var object:Object = {};
            private var objectProxy:ObjectProxy;

            private var timer:Timer;

            protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                objectProxy = new ObjectProxy(object);
                objectProxy.addEventListener(PropertyChangeEvent.PROPERTY_CHANGE, propertyChangeHandler);

                timer = new Timer(1000);
                timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
                timer.start();
            }

            protected function propertyChangeHandler(event:PropertyChangeEvent):void
            {
                label.text = (event.source).property;
            }

            protected function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void
            {
                objectProxy.property = Math.random() * 1000;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <s:Label id="label" />


</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're binding to object itself. That means, that the text of the label would change only if reference to object will be changed.

```
object={property:"Hello World"}
```

In this case the binding will do the job.

If you want the text to update after some property change, you should make this property Bindable.

```
public class MyObject {
    [Bindable]
    public var property:String;
}
```

Then declare the variable of class `MyObject` and bind to its `property`.